# Waterfall to change measure when drilling down

Tags: dax, hierarchy, selectedvalue, waterfall

I have a Free Cash Flow waterfall with different items of the FCF represented at the top level of the waterfall. The tricky moment comes with the Reserves item. When it grows it affects negatively the FCF. For example on the top level if we see -100 for Reserves it means they grew by 100 and affected FCF by -100.

What I want is that on the top level to see -100 for reserves, but when I drill down to Reserves to see the items and Reserves total change to 100.

I tried SELECTEDVALUE, FIRSTNONBLANK to include in condition (so that when we choose Reserves the formula change to minus value) but it affects also the top hierarchy (having 100 at the FCF level and also 100 at Reserves level which is not what I wanted) meaning PBI uses context for Reserves not only when we drill but also during the top level at category split.

What I think can be a solution is that if Waterfal visual passes the value of the category hierarchy and we could use it as a condition, so that when we are at FCF level we use normal formula and when we are drilled to Reserves we use opposite (minus) formula, but I don't know how to do it.